# How to differentiate exceptions in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to download a file using this code:

```
Try
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
        (fileUrl, Path.Combine(mySettings.filePath, fileName), _
        "", "", False, 500, True)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(translation.GetString("msgNavError") & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
End Try
```

This code works and shows an error like `Le nom distant n'a pas pu être résolu: '<hostname>'`. It would make no sense to compare like : `If ex.Message = "Le nom distant n'a pas pu être résolu: '<hostname>'" Then ...`, because the message is localized.

So how could I write this pseudo-code in VB.net ?

```
Catch ex As Exception
    If ex.NoNetworkWorkConnection Then
        MsgBox("Your computer is not connected to the network")
    Else If ex.ServerDidntRespond Then
        MsgBox("The server did not respond")
    Else
        MsgBox("Unexpected error : " & ex.Message)
    End If
End Try
```

I'm using Visual Basic 2008 Express.

Comment: Do avoid catch-em-all code, having to produce a decent diagnostic gets to be your next problem.  Catch WebException instead.  Its Status property gives you a language-independent hint of what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a try statement with multiple catch clauses like so

```
Try
'insert exception prone code here    
Throw New OutOfMemoryException
Throw New InvalidCastException

Catch ex As OutOfMemoryException
    Console.WriteLine("out of memory")

Catch ex2 As InvalidCastException
    Console.WriteLine("invalid cast")
End Try
```

Then if an out of memory exception is thrown the 1st catch clause will be executed if an invalid cast exception is thrown the 2nd catch clause will be executed.

You can change the exception type to whatever suits your needs as this is only an example

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but this raises the next question. How do I know that my ex will be an `InvalidCastException`. While debugging, is there something like `MsgBox(ex.ExceptionType)` to display "InvalidCastException" ?

Comment: You can use 'MsgBox(ex2.GetType().ToString())' which will display a message box containing 'System.InvalidCastException' is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. VB is still a pain, but at least this allows to go forward step by step.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the help page for [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you'll see a list of exceptions being throwned (ArgumentException, IOException, TimeoutException, SecurityException, WebException). Instead of catching a generic exception, catch the one you want.

```
Try
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
        (fileUrl, Path.Combine(mySettings.filePath, fileName), _
        "", "", False, 500, True)


Catch ex As ArgumentException
    MsgBox("ArgumentException")
Catch ex2 As IOException
    MsgBox("IOException")
End Try
```

Some exception like WebException have a property telling you which error number it is (ex [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: While the doc tells about WebException, Visual Studio claims `Type 'Webexception' is not defined`

Comment: @LorenzMeyer You might need to import System.Net or type System.Net.WebException

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TypeOf` keyword...

Here's and example:

```
Try
    CODEZ HERE
Catch ex As Exception
    If TypeOf ex Is OutOfMemoryException Then
        MsgBox("Out of memory exception")
    End If
End Try
```